# How to extract frequency information from an input audio stream (using PortAudio)?

Tags: python, voice, frequency, portaudio

I want to record sound (voice) using PortAudio (PyAudio) and output the corresponding sound wave on the screen. Hopeless as I am, I am unable to extract the frequency information from the audio stream so that I can draw it in Hz/time form.

---

Here's an example code snippet that records and plays recorded audio for five seconds, in case it helps any:

```
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

chunk = 1024
seconds = 5

stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                channels=1,
                rate=44100,
                input=True,
                output=True)

for i in range(0, 44100 / chunk * seconds):
    data = stream.read(chunk)
    stream.write(data, chunk)
```

I wish to extract the needed information from the above variable "data". (Or use some other high-level approach with PortAudio or another library with Python bindings.)

---

I'd be very grateful for any help! Even vaguely related tidbits of audio-analyzing wisdom are appreciated. :)

Comment: So you want to make a spectrum analyzer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is probably the Fourier transform of the audio data. There is several packages that can calculate that for you. `scipy` and `numpy` is two of them. It is often named "Fast Fourier Transform" (FFT), but that is just the name of the algorithm.

Here is an example of it's usage: https://svn.enthought.com/enthought/browser/Chaco/trunk/examples/advanced/spectrum.py

Answer (score 1):

The Fourier Transform will not help you a lot if you want the analysis to be conducted in both the frequency and time domain. You might want to have a look at "Wavelet Transforms". There is a package called pywavelets...
http://www.pybytes.com/pywavelets/#discrete-wavelet-transform-dwt

Comment: Taking Fourier transforms of each chunk as it comes in will be equivalent to a STFT, which is the same sort of thing as a wavelet transform.